# How do I scale videos etc by 200% on a 4K monitor but make sure each pixel is duplicated 4 times with no blur?

Tags: windows-7, video, resolution, images

I'm not seeing my exact question posted anywhere unfortunately.

I'm using Windows 7, as I like Windows 7 over Windows 10 for ease and privacy.

I bought a new 4K Lenovo monitor and a lot of my old data needs to be played scaled up by 200% so it looks the same size again. I see how to scale it up 200% by lowering the resolution to 1920x1080, but then upon zooming in both in person and in a paint program (to look into a screenshot I took) I see each pixel is not just duplicated 4 times so each pixel is 4 pixels, it is always some blurry "method" being used instead to upsample it, whether played in a different player or in chrome.

Even when I keep the resolution at 3840x2160 and simply drag it so it is about 2x bigger than 1280 pixels across, the video is still not showing the same picture, it's blurry.

I'm going to check on my Windows 10 laptop in Windows 10 changes anything but I don't know what to do. Perhaps, I'll have to stick with a 1920x1080 monitor and miss out on 1300:1 contrast ratio and 4K ability...as I can't find such a ISP panel type monitor like that.

Comment: If you're running at full resolution, it's up to the (video player) software.

Comment: Ok so, KMPlayer so far does it, you can make it double by 2 in a settings box, now I have to figure out why each Player has different color profiles some making my videos lighter some reder etc...at least my question is solved mostly then technically.